# What's wrong with this proof of almost sure limits?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of I.I.D. random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Let $Y_n=\prod_{k=1}^nX_k$. My task is to find the almost sure limit of $Y_n$. Here is my work:

It is somewhat obvious that the almost sure limit will be $0$, so I prove that this is the almost sure limit. Next, note the following:
$$0\leq \prod_{k=1}^nX_k \leq [\max_{k=1,...,n}X_n]^n, $$

and because $s^n$ converges to zero for all $|s|<1$, it follows that the the product must converge to zero.

I'm pretty sure that this proof is wrong because it seems for too simple. What's the issue if there is one?

Comment: You are assuming $s$ is a uniform bound, whereas in actuality you have $\prod_{k=1}^n X_k \leq S_n^n$, where $S_i = \max_{k=1,...,i} X_k.$ It is not even true for scalars $0 \leq s_i < 1$ that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n^n = 0$ -- for instance, $s_i = 1 - 1/i$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by snar, the problem in your approach is that the obtained bound for the maximum depends on $n$, that is $Y_n\leqslant M_n^n$ where $M_n=\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k$. And it is a priori possible that $M_n$ converges to $1$ hence  taking the limit may lead to an undetermined form. For example if $X_i=1-1/i$, then $M_n=1-1/n$ and $M_n^n\to 1/e$.

However, the previous configuration $X_i=1-1/i$ is actually almost surely impossible. The point is that for almost every $\omega$, an infinite amount of $X_n(\omega)$ will be smaller than $1/2$. This follows from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma applied to the sequence of independent events $A_n=\left\{X_n\leqslant 1/2\right\}$.

Comment: "However, the previous configuration is actually almost surely impossible." : isn't $M_n$ typically of size $1-1/n$ ? I wouldn't be surprised if $M_n^n$ has $[0,1]$ as limit set.

Comment: @D.Thomine I meant the configuration that $X_i=1-1/i$ and did not realize the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

$\ln Y_n= \sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i$, where $-\ln X_i$'s are i.i.d. $\exp(1)$ r.v.s. By the SLLN, $\ln Y_n^{1/n}\to -1$ a.s. and $Y_n^{1/n}\to e^{-1}$ a.s. Now use the fact that for each $k\ge 1$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}Y_n\le e^{-k}$ a.s.

Answer (score 0):

As D. Thomine's comment points out, not only does this proof not work (because $\max_{k\leq n}X_k$ depends on $n$ and can be close to $1$), but in fact this approach can't possibly work because almost surely $(\max_{k\leq n}X_k)^n\not\to 0$. To see this, note that $\Pr(X_n>1-1/(n+1))=1/(n+1)$, and so Borel-Cantelli implies there are infinitely many $n$ for which $X_n>1-1/(n+1)$, and hence $(\max_{k\leq n}X_k)^n>1/e$ infinitely often.

This means that your upper bound is simply too weak to give you what you need. An alternative bound which is good enough is that $Y_n\leq \left(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}\right)^n$ by AM-GM. Then the weak law of large numbers implies that almost surely $\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}<0.99$ for sufficiently large $n$.